# verifying multiple dropdown using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have multiple for loop created dynamically and named act1[ ], act2[ ], act3[ ].. up to act10[ ]. (may or may not count up to 10)

Now i want to submit the form and get all the values of the dropdown, but FIRST i want to verify if all the dropdown's value will not equal to '0' (i place the label in value=0,

ex.:

```
<option value=0>Select Activity..</option>
```

I try to put "onsubmit" attribute in form tag so that it will go first in the script before going to the next page. i have put an array to count the number of created rows. but now i am stock in verifying. here is my code:

```
<script>
function validateForm(){
var table = document.getElementById('activityTable');
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

for(var a=1; a<=rowCount; a++){
    var dd = document.getElementById("act"+ a +"[]");
    var ddval = dd.value;

    if (ddval!=0){
        //dont know what to put
    }
    else{
        //don't know what to put
    }
}
}
</script>
```

I also want the function to make the page stay at the same if it returns false and go to next page if it returns true.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the validateForm function in onsubmit and return a true (validated) or false (not validated) value. Something like this:

```
<!--* to validate before form submit, include 'return' inside your onsubmit tag *-->
<form name='myForm' action='path/to/file.php' onsubmit='return validateForm()' 
method='post'>
    <!-- Make sure your form tags are completely outside your table,
         mixing them could result in invalid HTML which causes problems 
         (for best results, I'd ditch the table and use CSS instead) -->
<table>Your Table Here</table>
</form>

<script>
function validateForm(event){
    var table = document.getElementById('activityTable');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var allValid = true;

    for(var a=1; a<=rowCount; a++){
        var dd = document.getElementById("act"+ a +"[]");
        var ddval = dd.value;

        if (ddval!=0){
            allValid = true;
            // open the console so you can watch logs, this helps 
            // for troubleshooting but remove those in production
            console.log(a + ' returned true ' + allValid);
        }
        else{
            allValid = false;
            console.log(a + ' returned false ' + allValid);
            // you shouldn't need this, but if returning false
            //  doesn't work try adding preventDefault (you'll also
            //  have to pass 'event' into your function above) 
               event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    // After you've looped through all rows, allValid will return true if
    // they were all true, or false if any of them were still 0.
    console.log('returning allValid as: ' + allValid;)
    return allValid; 
}
</script>
```

- check onsubmit="**return** validateForm()" (will return true or false)
- watch your form/table tags, invalid HTML could cause issues
- add console logs or alerts to help troubleshooting
- add event.preventDefault if false (but you shouldn't need this, returning false should stop the form from submitting)

If you try that and it's still not working, you might try posting your form/table code so we can better troubleshoot everything. Hope this helps!

Comment: so far this is ok, but how can i make my form stay in the same page if it return false and go to the next page if it returns true?

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer to add some more details and comments :)